How to obtain or make type O mortar
After brief research, I figured that I need type O mortar to do some repair work on the exterior of my 1941 brick veneer house.  Strangely, it seems that the big box home improvement stores don't sell type O mortar mix.  OK, so maybe I need to make it from ingredients.  But the big box stores also don't seem to sell hydrated lime, one key ingredient.  Is this work really so rare that the materials are not easily available to consumer or DIY buyers?  What is the best approach?

Please ask just one question per post. See Are recipes for render expressed by ratio of weight or ratio of volume? and How to do I calculate how much sand and cement needed for bedding mortar? for answers to your second question (now removed).

As I understand, when replacing failed mortar or filling gaps or re-pointing old brick veneer, low-strength mortar works best.  Hard, strong mortar would be harder and stronger than the bricks themselves, and would cause them to crack over the years as the wall is exposed to temperature changes and weathering.  I am OK with that.  Just surprised how hard it is to find the right mortar, or the ingredients.  Searches like "buy hydrated masonry lime" don't yield much about where to actually get the stuff.

Big box, schmig box. Try a masonry supply, not a store that only carries whatever products they think they can sell to homeowners for the maximum profit.

Try "slaked lime" instead it's the another name for the same substance. "calcium hydroxide" too. It's, as they say, "a dual use material", so you may get some funny looks if you're also buying a shovel, plastic sheeting, and duct tape.

There are companies which specialize in older "historic"  mortar mixtures; I dealt with them when repairing a crack in my 1890 foundation, and they weren't hard to find on the web. The ideal approach is to send them a sample of the existing mortar so they can match composition and color; I just ordered their general mix for that time period since it wasn't a highly visible repair.
The Usual Suspects (This Old House
and similar hone-renovation websites/vlogs) have articles and videos on this topic. That's where I started.

The Usual Suspects: This Old House and other moderately respectable online home improvement sites.

Ah. Not being a fan of such shows I'm not familiar with its initialism. You might extrapolate for clarity.

It's easy to find local masonry contractors online, and not hard to find far-away companies that sell type O mortar mixes mostly or entirely to contractors.  But the mortar mix manufacturers never seem to have "find a retailer" utilities on their websites.  I wondered if the mixes (or hydrated lime) have any physical retail outlet where I can drive and buy some.

I mail-ordered. You will have to do your own research to find out if someone near you stocks the product; that's a shopping question. Try asking the manufacturers if anyone near you is stocking retail. Or ask the contractors if they would special order it for you.

"Masonry supply" is indeed a business category, and searching that, I found a local company that would sell me one bag of type N mortar mix.  Not exactly type O, but less rigid than type S, and their guy said people use it for tuck pointing and repair.  So far, I used is successfully for a preliminary task, filling the gap between brick and siding around an old garage door frame I removed, prior to putting in a new frame.

In the process, discovered a new challenge -- the mortar I purchased dries to a light neutral grey, while the old 1941 mortar is a warm beige color.  Now I need to figure out how to color the mortar.  Mail order is probably ten times more expensive between the service and shipping heavy material, but might handle the color issue if the supplier includes that service.

Sand color varies... This is indeed one of the reasons you might want to pay extra to have them match a sample. In my case it's in a not-very-visible corner further obscured by a cabinet and in the basement, so color match wasn't worth paying a small amount extra for.  I'm tempted to suggest a light touch of watercolor paint, but gods only know how well they'll retain their color. Mail-order really wasn't that expensive as house repairs go; I think it worked out to somewhere between US$2 and $4 a pound shipping included. Prices may have changed since then.

You might or might not come out ahead if you can find a contractor near you who is willing to special order it as part of their next shipment, piggy-backing in their freight cost but paying a surcharge for the assistance, but I'm not sure it's worth the optimization.
